# Requests for review on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a designed and prototyped a circuit, and it works.  I'd like to get community review of the design though, in the same way that I can get code review at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Are review requests on-topic here?  I've checked the [FAQ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but can't find anything specific.

Comment: I asked a review-type question, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53609/schematic-critique-phy-interface-with-rj45-magnetics, so as long as you are asking specific questions and not being overly broad it should be OK.

Comment: By the way, [tag:hdl] questions are also on-topic for Code Review, if anyone is interested.  [Example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/54786/9357)

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2513/pcb-review-questions-acceptable-separate-se-site/2520

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general it's quite a broad question, but (IMO) can be a good one as long as you:

- verify that the prototype works,
- explain the design choices you made
- express your perplexities and doubts you had in the design phase.

So in general I'd say that instead of just saying "please look at my design" you could ask for clarifications and feedback on the aspects you're not that confident about.

Comment: Agreed. Design reviews (in general) work best if the designer has specific questions for the audience. Otherwise it's basically a "Where's Waldo" problem.

Comment: @W5VO worse, more like "how many Waldos are there?"

Comment: @W5VO but isn't that what a review is all about? Have someone more experienced than you have a look at your design and point out gotcha's and best practices?

Comment: @jippie I think that it can be done, but requires some discipline from the poster, otherwise it becomes too broad

Comment: @clabacchio I worry more about anonymous down- and close-votes without any lead as to how to improve the question.

Comment: @jippie it's an eternal discussion, but votes are anonymous by design, it's part of the game.